# What is equivalent class/primitive with respect to DART for Java Equivalent?

Tags: dart

```
1. Java int[] - integer array
2. Java Object[] - object array
3. Java inputstream - ex: stream received after by listening to TCP - socket
4. Java byte[] - read from file or received as packet from socket via TCP
5. Java char[]
```

Need help on the equivalent class/primitives in DART.

Answer (score 2):

1. `List<int>`. Create with `List<int>()` or `<int>[]`
2. `List<Object>`. Create with `List<Object>()` or `<Object>[]`
3. `Stream<List<int>>`
4. `List<int>`. Create with `List<int>()` or `Uint8List.fromList(<int>[1, 2, 3])`
5. same as 4.

See also https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/misc/sMEMCGYAYN8

Comment: Do I need to specify `<int>` even on the constructor?
Even if I'm already using `List<int>` as type?

Comment: Yes for `List<int> l = List<int>()`, no for `List<int> l = [];` but you can omit the type of the variable `var l = List<int>()` or `var l = <int>[]`

Comment: What would happen using `List<int> l = List()` I couldn't see any differences while coding about that.

Comment: I mixed it up with https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/31865 `List<int> l = List()` is fine.